# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I want to use KafkaAvroDeserializer with springboot ,but i faild, Error report when starting ,here is my code and exception infomation

Is there any jar missing?

can I

pom:

```
        <!-- avro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

code :

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> conConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
        conConfigMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        ...
        conConfigMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        conConfigMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
        conConfigMap.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
        return conConfigMap;
    }
```

exception information:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where/how are you running your application? Assuming you're not running from some IDE, then you need to create a fat-jar. You also shouldn't need the common config/utils dependencies

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
I resolved adding the **kafka-serde-tools** libraries from confluent libs.

Answer (score 1):

If Anyone is still facing this issue then it'd be solved by adding Kafka Schema Serializer jar in classpath.

You can download jar from given below link

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-schema-serializer/7.4.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some packages like:

`io.confluent.kafka.serializers`

exist in two different JARs:

1. kafka-avro-serializer
2. kafka-schema-serializer

The Java module system does not allow this for JARs on the module path. The first JAR loaded will establish who owns the package name and, even if the package name exists in another jar, the other JAR will not be searched by class loading mechanism.

Because `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe` exists in kafka-schema-serializer JAR and its super class `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer` exists in kafka-avro-serializer JAR, you will not be able to load these classes using the module path.

The solution is to put the problematic JARs on the "unnamed" module path (or not to use module-info)

Answer (score 0):

After adding the below mentioned dependency, issue got resolved:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-serde-tools-package</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```