# Kafka java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Have problem with Kafka, error

> 05-Jan-2023 11:19:47.532 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-32] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jpublish] in context with path [/DS] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", url);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("max.block.ms", 10000);
props.put("group.id", "group");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(KafkaJsonSchemaSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

Producer<String, Payment> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, Payment>(props);
ProducerRecord<String, Payment> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Payment>(topic, uuid, message);

producer.send(record);

producer.close();
```

lib kafka on project

[image: library]

class `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe` i can import and no error

[image: import]

any suggest ?

already tried including `kafka-serde-tools` from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280239/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-io-confluent-kafka-serializers-abstractkafkasc), but not working

Comment: this was already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280239/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-io-confluent-kafka-serializers-abstractkafkasc

Comment: i have tried but not working

Comment: Please use Maven/Gradle (as in your new question), not manual JAR files...